# Ethtx tasks can be used with webhook jobs

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, chainlink

I would like to know if ethtx tasks can be used with webhook jobs. I tried to run the job from the operator UI and it returns an internal server error, when I look up the logs it says that

```
Expected at least one task to be final             pipeline/common.go:212           logger=1.2.1@168d34a stacktrace=github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/services/pipeline.TaskRunResults.FinalResult
        /chainlink/core/services/pipeline/common.go:212
```

which I assume it means it cannot work unless ethtx is a final task such as jsonparse/multiply etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webhook jobs are limited in the task flow I believe, such that there is no support for webhook jobs and on-chain tx's related to that webhook job. In general, node operators utilize webhook jobs, to verify there job-spec code within the "`observationSource`" such that a bridge api endpoint is properly connected, and filtering to the correct path that the downstream user wants. Because there is no on-chain tx recorded, the testing can be done immediately after job-creation and no test smart contract to ping the oracle/node.

https://docs.chain.link/docs/jobs/types/webhook/